# How to find third Sunday date for all months between a date range in R and their respective values

Tags: r, lubridate

For a particular date range, for example between 2020-01-29 and 2021-05-02, I want to find out dates for every 3rd Sunday of every month along with their associated `value` in a `data.frame`.

Additionally, if there is any 5th Monday in any month then I want to obtain its date and corresponding value in a separate `data.frame`.

Please note that it needs to be between a date range from those given in the `data.frame`.

```
## for creating data frame in R wrt dates and values
dates_seq<-(seq(as.Date("2019/12/28"), by = "day", length.out = 1000))
dates_seq<-as.data.frame(dates_seq)
values<-seq(1:1000)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(dates_seq,values))
```

To summarize, I want to find the third Sunday date for every month and it's corresponding value and the fifth Monday for every month if there is any along with it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base R approach :

```
# Get date between 2020-01-29 and 2021-05-0
temp <- subset(df, dates_seq >= as.Date('2020-01-29') & 
                    dates_seq <= as.Date('2021-05-02'))
#Add weekday
temp$week_day <- weekdays(temp$dates_seq)
#Add week number for each month
temp$week_number <- ave(temp$week_day, temp$week_day, 
                        format(temp$dates_seq, "%Y-%m"), FUN = seq_along)
#Subset 3rd Sunday and 5th Monday
subset(temp, week_number == 3 & week_day == 'Sunday' | 
             week_number == 5 & week_day == 'Monday')


#     dates_seq values week_day week_number
#51  2020-02-16     51   Sunday           3
#79  2020-03-15     79   Sunday           3
#94  2020-03-30     94   Monday           5
#114 2020-04-19    114   Sunday           3
#142 2020-05-17    142   Sunday           3
#177 2020-06-21    177   Sunday           3
#185 2020-06-29    185   Monday           5
#205 2020-07-19    205   Sunday           3
#233 2020-08-16    233   Sunday           3
#248 2020-08-31    248   Monday           5
#268 2020-09-20    268   Sunday           3
#296 2020-10-18    296   Sunday           3
#324 2020-11-15    324   Sunday           3
#339 2020-11-30    339   Monday           5
#359 2020-12-20    359   Sunday           3
#387 2021-01-17    387   Sunday           3
#422 2021-02-21    422   Sunday           3
#450 2021-03-21    450   Sunday           3
#458 2021-03-29    458   Monday           5
#478 2021-04-18    478   Sunday           3
```

Comment: could you explain me  this step                                                                                                                  
temp$week_number <- ave(temp$week_day, temp$week_day, format(temp$dates_seq, "%Y-%m"), FUN = seq_along)

Comment: It assigns count of weekday for every month. So first Sunday of the month would get 1, first Monday would get 1....second Sunday would get 2, ....third Sunday would get 3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As in `lubridate` Sundays are the 1st day of the week, this code will give you a data frame containing all third Sundays:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(dates_seq = as.Date(dates_seq)) %>%
  mutate(year = year(dates_seq),
         month = month(dates_seq),
         day = wday(dates_seq)) %>%
  filter(day == 1) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  slice(3)
```

You could do a match with the original data frame to find the row index.

Comment: This does not consider the date range 2020-01-29 and 2021-05-02, does it?

Comment: @machine no it does not include